DiffSharp Model.save() and Model.saveState() not working
DiffSharp Model.save() and Model.saveState() are not working, getting the following error message:
System.NotSupportedException: BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information.                                          
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)                        
   at DiffSharp.Util.UtilAutoOpens.saveBinary[T](T object, String fileName)                                                                     
   at DiffSharp.Model.ModelBase.saveState(String fileName, FSharpOption`1 noDiff)                                                               
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0047>.$FSI_0047.main@() in d:\Martin\Coding\F#\DiffSharp Example5.fsx:line 2402                                          
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)                            
   at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithNoArgs(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr)                                                 
Stopped due to error

Any solution to this?

If you're using .NET8, then I suspect this to be the cause, as indicated in the first line of the error message. The new version of .NET, dotnet8, make BinaryFormatter throw an exception during runtime.
If this is the cause of your problem, then you could to send an issue to the maintainer of your library, or downgrade the framework.

In any case, you don't provide any reproducible code.
